# Swapping integral and sum using dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, summation, lebesgue-integral

> Show that
>   $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty t^{s/2-1}e^{-\pi n^2t}dt
>  = \int_0^\infty t^{s/2-1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2t} dt
> $$
>   with $s > 1$ using the dominated convergence theorem.

If I have understood correctly, I can define $f_k:= \sum_{n=1}^k t^{s/2-1}e^{-\pi n^2t}$ which I have already been able to show integrable and that it converges pointwise ($f = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} f_k$). Now the last part of the requirements of the theorem: I struggle to find an integrable function $g$ with $|f_k| \leq g$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is really monotone convergence theorem. Since all terms in the $f_k$ series are positive, $f_k$ is increasing. The equation will hold even if both are infinity and $f$ is not integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on @zugzug's comment, we can prove this using the monotone convergence theorem. Let $f_n(t) = \sum_{k=1}^n t^{s/2-1}e^{-k^2\pi t}$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$. Then $f_n(t)\geqslant 0$ and
\begin{align}
f_{n+t}(t) - f_n(t) &=  \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} t^{s/2-1}e^{-k^2\pi t} - \sum_{k=1}^n t^{s/2-1}e^{-k^2\pi t}\\
&= t^{s/2-1}e^{-k^2\pi t} >0
\end{align}
for all $t\geqslant 0$, so the limit $f:=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n$ is measurable and
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(t)\ \mathsf dt&=
 \int_0^\infty t^{s/2-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2\pi t}\ \mathsf dt\\
 &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^\infty f_n(t)\ \mathsf dt\\ &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty  f_n(t)\ \mathsf dt\\ &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty t^{s/2-1} e^{-n^2\pi t}\ \mathsf dt.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. I have one question about the monotone convergence theorem. In my book there is a version of this theorem that also concludes integrability, if $sup_n \int f_n < \infty$, which would be the same thing as finding an integrable function $g$ with $|f_n| < g$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
But it is only necessary to show the monotony of $(f_n)$ in order to be able to use the swapping part of limit and sum?

Comment: The monotone convergence theorem does not imply that the limit function is integrable. Its integral may be infinite.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, what you are trying to do is overkill since monotone convergence is enough. But if you want to use dominated convergence you can do
\begin{align}
|f_k|&= \sum_{n=1}^k t^{s/2-1}e^{-\pi n^2t}=t^{s/2-1}e^{-\pi t}\,\sum_{n=1}^k e^{-\pi (n^2-1)t}\\ \ \\
&\leq t^{s/2-1}e^{-\pi t}\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\pi (n^2-1)t}\\ \ \\
&\leq t^{s/2-1}e^{-\pi t}\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\pi nt}\\ \ \\
&=t^{s/2-1}e^{-\pi t}\,\frac1 {1-e^{-\pi t}}\\ \ \\
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had a similar solution, but it is not integrable, is it?

Comment: Of course it is. That's the point!

Comment: But only for $Re(s) > 2$?
For $s = \frac{3}{2}$, e.g., wolfram states that it doesn't converge.

Comment: True. For $s<2$ the integral does not converge, so you cannot expect to use dominated convergence. I mean, both sides are infinity so the equality holds, you don't need a theorem for that.